# Ubuntu goes black after kali tools installation reboot

Tags: command-line, 14.04, apt

Whenever I try to install Kali Tools on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have to reboot and it comes on but it shows a black screen (no backlight). I can open a terminal but I don't know how to use it.

These are the commands I used if it's needed.

sudo passwd root

sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'

sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback

sudo apt-get install gdebi && sudo apt-get install synaptic

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whick Kali Tools you were trying to install?

If you were using repositories hosted on launchpad.net e.g.

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main

Kali tools are not supported for Ubuntu 14.04. You can check the link

https://launchpad.net/~wagungs/+archive/ubuntu/kali-linux

Latest Ubuntu version supported is 13.04.

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't know It wasn't supported yet.

Comment: You can install many useful kali tools just from their websites though and it works fine. e.g. metasploit, Burp etc.

If this answer was helpful you can accept it..thanks :)

Comment: How do I install Bully?

Answer (score 0):

Change `lightdm.conf` back to:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
allow-guest=false
```

without the spaces.